# Creating a class in Selenium to run Chrome, which can be called in code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have hundreds of tests that all use the code,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Temp\\Sel.4.14.1\\Demo\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Development\\Utilities\\Air-Automatic-Testing\\SmokeTest\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe");
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    
    String url = "https://autotest:44300";
    LogFile.logfile("String URL " + url);
    driver.manage().timeouts();
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Instead of coping and pasting the code in to each test, can I create a class with the code and then just call it?

If I need a class for options and one for driver, then that's fine, but I don't understand how to create the class type.

E.g., I can create a class called startbrowser with the code,

```
public static WebDriver driver(WebDriver driver) throws Exception {

    //String url = ReadConfigFile.readconf(type).getProperty("url");
    String url = "https://autotest:44300";
    LogFile.logfile("String URL " + url);
    // WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    LogFile.logfile("Instanciate WebDriver, launch url and maximize screen");
    return driver;
}
```

But I don't know how to add the options to the class or what data type to use for a class for just options?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can see my version here which uses a factory design pattern: https://github.com/petecalkins/Browsermator-Selenium4/blob/master/src/browsermator4/com/DriverFactory.java